# how to execute sql server stored procedure on php?

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures

i want to know why i cannot call any stored procedure on php file
it always return false
but when i call it on sql server directly, it shows my data

here is my php:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/simda/classes/koneksi.php');
global $conn;
$kon = new koneksi();
$conn = $kon->bukaKoneksi();
$params = array();
$query = "EXEC dbo.RptSPJ_Pengeluaran '2013','1','1','1','0','1','1'";

$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$rs_test = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);
if ($rs_test != NULL) {
    $num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($rs_test);
    echo $num_rows;
}
else {
    echo 'wrong';
}
```

if i echo the query and execute it on sql server, it shows my data
is there anything wrong?
please help me
thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211150/exec-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-php