# Call a SQL Server stored proc with parameters in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

Based on this :

[how to execute sql server stored procedure on php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418151/how-to-execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-on-php)

Tried the following :

```
$odbc = odbc_connect($DB1_ODBC,$DB1_USER,$DB1_PWD);  // proven to be fully functionnal
$result = odbc_exec($odbc,"CALL importClient( @name = 'hello',@number = 457)");
```

It does not call the stored procedure, i can't see any error code.

I replaced `"CALL` by `"EXEC` but it's not working in either cases.

Otherwise, the stored procedure can be run by using the same credentials to connect to the database, and using this SQL statement :

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[importClient] @name = 'hello',@number = 457
```

I couldn't find anything helpful, neither think of another way, and I definitely need the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked with :

```
$result = odbc_exec($odbc,"EXECUTE importClient @name = 'hello', @number = 457");
```

But this isn't protected against SQL injections, so it might not be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($odbc, "call dbo.importClient(?, ?)");
odbc_execute($stmt, ["hello", 457]);
```

Using a prepared statement will protect your code from SQL injection attacks. Use this when you replace your literal values with variables containing user input.

Comment: Error code is the following : `odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number`