# Cant call stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can someone point out whats wrong with my php code for calling stored procedure in mssql. The following sql query works fine in mssql studio:

```
EXEC updateRecord 'Record','Closed','Jon','query test4','',''
```

Here is the php code that Im using to try and call the updateRecord:

```
<?php
 $Record = $_POST['record'];
 $Stat = $_POST['Status'];
 $Tech = $_POST['Tech'];
 $Action = $POST['Action'];
 $Date = date("Y/m/d");
 $time = date("G:i:s");
 //connect to sql
 $hostname = '127.0.0.1\SQLserver';
 $options = array('Database'=>'CallHistory', 'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8');
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, $options); 
 if(!is_resource($conn))
 { 
 echo 'Could not connect: ';
 var_dump(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL)); 
 exit(0);
 }

 //    echo "Success";
 //    sqlsrv_close($conn);

 // DB queries

 if (empty($_POST['record']) && empty($_POST['Statut'])&&empty($_POST['Tech']) && empty($_POST['Action']))
 {
 echo "CHoose at least one";
 }
else
{
$query1 = "exec updateRecord $Record,$Stat,$Tech,$Action,$Date,$time";
}
$ask = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
sqlsrv_fetch($ask);
.........
?>
```

What am I forgetting....?
The server seems to return an empty response and the actual record is not updated.

Comment: Try it like this: $query1 = "CALL updateRecord $Record,$Stat,$Tech,$Action,$Date,$time";

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run this code?

Comment: @AslanShemilov same effect no change no error

Comment: @Gary Ewan Park no error, just an empty response

Comment: Shouldn't that be $query1 = "CALL updateRecord( $Record,$Stat,$Tech,$Action,$Date,$time )"

Comment: @jeff tried that also ...same effect

Answer (score 0):

got it to work:

```
$query1 = "EXEC updateRecord @Record = '$Record', @Status = '$Stat', @Tech = '$Tech', @Date = '$Date', @time = '$time', @Actions = '$Action'";
```

[thanks to this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911709) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911709