# Exec SQL Server stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I tried to call a SQL Server stored procedure from PHP.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[tester]
    @id NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tab TABLE (myxml XML)

    INSERT INTO @tab(myxml)
        SELECT map 
        FROM forms 
        WHERE mapid = @id

    SELECT * FROM @tab
END
```

and my PHP script:

```
<?php
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "sa","PWD" => "mypass","Database" =>  "database");  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    $tsql = "exec tester 'FORMgRGVL7bfpEnpBpg7vz2sHoKAs5zxU5LW'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    if ($result === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        $response=array('response'=>'notok','data'=>'loyo');
        $serverresponse=JSON_encode($response);
    } else {
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $response=array('response'=>'ok','data'=>$row[0]);
        $serverresponse=JSON_encode($response);
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
} else {
    $response=array('response'=>'notok','flag'=>$flag,'data'=>'cc');        
    $serverresponse = $serverresponse=JSON_encode($response);
}

echo ($serverresponse);
?>
```

When I execute the stored procedure from SSMS it returns the value as expected, but when I execute it from PHP, it returns null.

Comment: why sqlsrv_query? this should be `sqlsrv_execute`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a stored procedure in php using sqlsrv and "?" style parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575135/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-php-using-sqlsrv-and-style-parameters)

Comment: my problem is the return value from the server always null even when execute was success

Answer (score 1):

**Explanations:**

You need to put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your stored procedure to prevent returning the number of rows affected by the T-SQL statements as part of the result set. This is the reason for your `NULL` results.

As a note, always use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.

**Example:**

There are errors in your script, which are fixed in the example:

- `sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt)` is changed to `sqlsrv_free_stmt($result)`
- variable `$flag` is not defined
- `$serverresponse = $serverresponse=JSON_encode($response)` is changed to `$serverresponse = json_encode($response)`

T-SQL:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[tester]
   @id nvarchar(max)
as
begin
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   declare @tab table (myxml xml)

   insert into @tab(myxml)
   select map from forms where mapid=@id

   select * from @tab
end
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$flag = "";    
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "mypass", "Database" => "database"); 

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn) {
    $tsql = "exec tester ?";
    $params = array('FORMgRGVL7bfpEnpBpg7vz2sHoKAs5zxU5LW');
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
    if ($result === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        $response = array('response'=>'notok', 'data'=>'loyo');
        $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $response = array('response'=>'ok', 'data'=>$row[0]);
        $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
} else {
    $response = array('response'=>'notok', 'flag'=>$flag, 'data'=>'cc');        
    $serverresponse = json_encode($response);
}

echo ($serverresponse);

?>
```